# Hide render on all but one object on several collections in different layers

Tags: python, scripting

Let's say I have two layers.
In total, I have three collections excluding "scene collection". ("Collection", "back", and "front").
In "back" and "front" I have the same amount of objects.

I have an input (int ID)
What I'm trying to do is to hide render on all objects in "back" and "front", and then unhide renders based on that input.

Comment: You can use driver functions (python-like).   Let's say that by (int ID) you have a custom property on a single object. In that case you can 1) hover over the property, right-click (RMB) and "Copy as New Driver", then 2) go to the objects "Visibility", hover over the Show In Renders and RMB Paste Driver. for the property, 0 will make it renderable, '1' will eliminate it from a Render. You would then paste this to each objects "Render" control. I'm not sure there's a way to use a Driver for a collection's "Disable in Renders", sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@james_t pointed out in a comment that I could use drivers.
So I managed to make a solution by looking into drivers.

1. Type the following into the text editor:

```py
import bpy

# myObj.003 -> 3
# myObj     -> 0
def getId(obj):
    if len(obj.name.split('.')) == 1:
        return 0
    return float(obj.name.split('.')[1])

bpy.app.driver_namespace['getId'] = getId 


def isId(var, obj):
    var -= getId(obj)
    return 0 >= var or var > 1

bpy.app.driver_namespace['isId'] = isId
```

2. Run the code.
3. Right-click (RMB) on the target property (in this case the "Disable in renders") and press "Add Driver".
4. in the driver do the following:

   - set Type to "Scripted Expression".
   - enable "Use Self".
   - Add some sort of input variable named "var".
   - set Expression to the following code:

```py
isId(var, self)
```

[image: Driver Property][image: Gif of final solution]